# how to get data by row and column - UFT

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I'm using UFT(former QTP) and I don't know how to get data by column and row from a **Radgrid Telerik** table.
cheers

Comment: Are you able to find that as a normal table. Kindly add a code or something that you tried to take the value from the conventional way. Please share your inference

Comment: Hello. I'm not familiar with **Radgrid Telerik** myself, but as per the comments in [this topic](http://community.hpe.com/t5/Unified-Functional-Testing/Is-QTP-11-0-support-Telerik-WPF-controls/td-p/5747535) you will probably need to create your own Extensibility add-ins to support it, as it is not supported from HP by default

Comment: @VictorMoraes - how can I create my own extensibility ?

Comment: Sorry, but I am not able to help you with that either, as I have no experience with that. I'd advise you to seek for help with HP help and support forums. I believe you will be in better hands there